# Collection Iteration not showing proper values?

Tags: java, collections, tree

I'm iterating through a simple Collection. I populate the Collection with random Integer objects, defined via the following:

```
    Collection<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
    treeSet = createFilledCollection(10000, treeSet);
    printContents(hashSet);



    //populate the Collection
    private Collection<Integer> createFilledCollection(long size, Collection<Integer> collection){
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
        
        Integer integer = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        collection.add(integer);
        
    }
    
    return collection;
}
```

Then I iterate through the contents of this `Collection` and print it's contents through the `printContents(hashSet);`

```
private void printContents(Collection<Integer> collection) {
    
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    
    for(Integer i : collection) {
        
        if(i > 500)
            break;
        System.out.println(i);
        
        joiner.add(i.toString());
    }
    
    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
    
}
```

I'm expecting to see a random assortment of numbers

10 41 2 23 44 65 6... 19 11

(as I add random numbers through the `createFilledCollection(Integer size, Collection collection)` method. However, I get the following output:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6... 98 99

Why am I not seeing random numbers? (*and yes, I checked to make sure I am not printing the iteration point*)

Comment: Why would you expect random order from an *ordered set*? Javadoc of [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) specifically says: *"The elements are **ordered** using their natural ordering"*.

Comment: If you wanted to keep the original random order, use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (any kind) or a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Comment: @Andreas I think I worded it badly - I expect the random values I pass in to be in some sort of order, but I still expect to see the random values I passed in. Right now, it just increases linearly from 0.

Comment: Of course. Why would you expect otherwise? `TreeSet` is a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and javadoc says: *"A collection that contains **no duplicate** elements"*. --- You randomly generate **10000** integers in range 0-99. Since it is highly unlikely that an integer in that range is not generated randomly *at least once* when generating that many of them, and since duplicates are removed, you end up with one of each value in the range, and they are sorted because it's a `TreeSet`.

Comment: @Andreas wow, I should delete this question lol. That makes much more sense now. Thank you Andreas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using TreeSet, The ordering of the elements is maintained by a set using their natural ordering whether or not an explicit comparator is provided.

Change TreeSet to like HashSet and you will get the desired output

Comment: OP said *"I'm expecting to see a **random** assortment of numbers"*. --- `HashSet` does not return values in random order.

Comment: Right, I am using a TreeSet - does it not store the random values I populated it with in order? I'm expecting to see those random numbers in some type of order, the number I'm reading from the set have no meaning.

Also, I pass in a `HashSet` and it produces the same output...